# Jest/react-testing-library: Clicking a button didn't update the value in test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

### Initial Question

I have a simple increment/decrement component.

It shows a number count and 2 buttons that either increment or decrements by 1.

There is also an input; if a numeric value is supplied in the input then the buttons use the input value instead of 1 to inc/decrement.

I have this test:

```
it(`should increment by input value, if value > 0`, () => {
  const { input } = setup();

  // Change input value to 4
  fireEvent.change(input, {target: { value: 4}});

  // Find and click +n button
  const btn = screen.getByText(`+n`);
  fireEvent.click(btn);

  // Find and check updated count
  const updatedCount = parseInt(screen.getByTestId(`count`).textContent, 10)
  expect(updatedCount).toBe(4);
})
```

**The Issue:** The updated count here is returning 1 (default in `useState`), I expected 4.

`expect(parseInt(input.value, 10)).toBe(4)` passes and the input `onChange` is hooked up.

**The Question:** Why is the updated input value not being used?

**Additional Info:** Although I'm not sure, I thought maybe it wasn't updating the `useState` on change, so I also added a keyboard event to hit the enter key on the input, after I changed its value. I was hoping to further simulate a user and update the state but I had no luck with this.

Any help much appreciated! Apologies for anything that's out of place, I've only been looking at Jest/RTL the last couple, of days.

---

---

### Reply Info

**Test Component:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const MyTest = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [value, setValue] = useState(1);

  const incCount = (n) => {
    if (n !== 0) {
      count + n <= 10 && setCount((currCount) => currCount + n);
      return;
    }

    if (count < 10) setCount((currCount) => currCount + 1);
  };
  const decCount = (n) => {
    if (n !== 0) {
      count - n >= 0 && setCount((currCount) => currCount - n);
      return;
    }

    if (count > 0) {
      setCount((currCount) => currCount - 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div>value: {value}</div>
      <div data-testid="count">{count}</div>

      <br />

      <label htmlFor="inp">N Input</label>
      <br />
      <input
        type="texts"
        placeholder="inc or dec by num"
        id="inp"
        value={value}
        onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <button type="button" onClick={() => decCount(parseInt(value))}>
        -n
      </button>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => incCount(parseInt(value))}>
        +n
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default MyTest;
```

**Test:**

```
import React from 'react';
import {screen, fireEvent, render, cleanup, waitFor} from '@testing-library/react';
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import MyTest from './myTest';

describe(`Increment and decrement the count when relevant button is pressed`, () => {
  // Get component
  const setup = () => {
    const utils = render(<MyTest />)
    const initCount = parseInt(screen.getByTestId(`count`).textContent, 10)
    const input = screen.getByLabelText(`N Input`);
    return {
      initCount,
      input,
      ...utils
    }
  };

  // ...other tests here

  it(`should increment by input value, if value > 0`, () => {
    const { input } = setup();

    // Change input value to 4
    fireEvent.change(input, {target: { value: 4}});

    // Find and click +n button
    const btn = screen.getByText(`+n`);
    fireEvent.click(btn);

    // Find and check updated count
    const updatedCount = parseInt(screen.getByTestId(`count`).textContent, 10)
    expect(updatedCount).toBe(4);
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your type attribute. Change this

```js
<input type="texts" {...} />
```

To this

```js
<input type="text" {...} />
```

And the test will work again. My guess is that by specifying the `<input>` an invalid `type` attribute, the library doesn't know which [role](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance) your `input` is, so it cannot handle the `onchange` event properly.

I'm not sure why updating to the new version of `react-scripts` and `@testing-library/react` will fix the problem even if you leave the typo there though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for chipping in. After reading your reply I saw this on the RTL docs ..."React Testing Library wraps render and fireEvent in a call to act already so most cases should not require using it manually"... so I tried but it rendered the same results. I instead used waitFor() and this is passing the test. That said, I'm not sure if the expect() inside the waitFor() is passing or the waitFor() isn't triggering at all. I have tried to display the component with debug() inside the waitFor() but nothing shows up - as if the code in the waitFor() block isn't triggering.

Comment: Can you add the component definition in your question, so I can try to reproduce it in my local. And yeah the `act` wrapping may be unnecessary here, I forgot `fireEvent` is from RTL. @11-

Comment: Thanks for taking the time @NearHuscarl I've added further info hopefully this will help.

Comment: @phurst-so your test [runs fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HO3mX.png) on my machine. This is my [package.json](https://github.com/NearHuscarl/so-toolkit/blob/master/package.json). Please provide your jest and RTL versions

Comment: Well, that's really odd... I'm using CRA so jest/RTL are built-in and I cannot see their versions - unless you know how? You seem to have a lot in your package.json, did you put that together or eject a CRA? You can see here I'm definitely getting a 1 returned, seen here: [returned 1](https://ibb.co/mvTtn70)

Comment: Looking at your package.json I took anything relating to RTL and react and replaced all my dependencies with those. [Before/After screenies](https://imgur.com/a/dnTBCQ5). It's all working now, but I still don't know which changed caused the fix, and what that fix was. Looking at the screenies the only difference is the version of react-scripts and the fact react-testing-library is present in yours - but RTL should be built-in, so why would I need to add the dependency? @NearHuscarl

Comment: @phurst-so I believe I know why the test failed. But I'm not sure why updating to the new version of `react-scripts` and RTL fix it.

Comment: @NearHascarl In response to your answer refactor; the typo obviously needs correcting (good spot :)) but doesn't seem to be to the actual cause, as it can be seen working here: [Working with typo](https://imgur.com/a/aCjZkvc)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223242/discussion-between-nearhuscarl-and-phurst-so).

Comment: In the end, this was a typo in the component. A daft mistake but big thanks anyway. Still, it's odd that it all worked with the typo still in, and NearHuscarl's packages instead of mine.